# How can I prevent the inside content of a grid-area from sticking out in a downward direction?

Tags: css, grid-layout

I've been working on building a grid-layout area that contains some "panels" and "rows". Each panel consists of a header and main elements, and some of the main elements have some items inside.

Here is my demo. https://codepen.io/bunatree/pen/Vwjqmod

```css
#canvas {
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template:
    "bar1   bar1  "
    "panel1 panel2"
    "bar2   bar2  "
    "panel3 panel4"
    /1fr    1fr
}

#sidebar {
  grid-area: side;
  background-color: #c99;
}

#panel1 {
  grid-area: panel1;
}

#panel2 {
  grid-area: panel2;
}

#panel3 {
  grid-area: panel3;
}

#panel4 {
  grid-area: panel4;
}

#bar1 {
  grid-area: bar1;
}

#bar2 {
  grid-area: bar2;
}

.panel {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.bar {
  background-color: rgba(0,128,255,0.5);
  padding: 20px;
}

header {
  background-color: #9c9;
  padding: 10px;
}

main {
  min-height: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #c9c;
  /* I set this 100% height here so that
     the bottom of the main area reaches
     the bottom of the panel div. */
 height: 100%;
}

.item {
  background-color: #cc9;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas">
  <div class="bar" id="bar1">Bar 1</div>
  <div class="panel" id="panel1">
    <header>Panel 1</header>
    <main>
      <div class="item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    </main>    
  </div>
  <div class="panel" id="panel2">
    <header>Panel 2</header>
    <main>
      <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    </main>    
  </div>
  <div class="bar" id="bar2">Bar 2</div>
  <div class="panel" id="panel3">
    <header>Panel 3</header>
    <main>
    </main>      
  </div>
  <div class="panel" id="panel4">
    <header>Panel 4</header>
    <main>
      <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, it makes the main area stick out in a downward direction.

[Some main element overflows in a downward direction.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uB6Vr.png)

Without the 100% height setting, the overflowing issue is solved but the height of the main element fits the total height of the inner items.

[Without the 100% height setting, the height of the main element is short when there is no inner item.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPlxS.png)

So, my question is how I can extend the height of the main element without sticking it out regardless of the number of the inner items.

I would be very happy if someone helps me. Thank you.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for your advice. I am quite a newbie here and I didn't know about the snippets. Sorry for my improper explanations without the snippets. I just pasted my HTML and CSS codes into a snippet and put it into my question above. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by myself.

I had to;

- Stop using 100% height for the main element. (This makes it overflow from the grid area.)
- Set display: flex and flex-direciton: column to the .panel element.
- Set flex-grow: 1 to the main element to extend it vertically.

Run the code below and you will see the height of the main element (background: purple) vertically fits the inside of the panel element (background: gray).

```css
#canvas {
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template:
    "bar1   bar1  "
    "panel1 panel2"
    "bar2   bar2  "
    "panel3 panel4"
    /1fr    1fr
}

#panel1 {
  grid-area: panel1;
}

#panel2 {
  grid-area: panel2;
}

#panel3 {
  grid-area: panel3;
}

#panel4 {
  grid-area: panel4;
}

#bar1 {
  grid-area: bar1;
}

#bar2 {
  grid-area: bar2;
}

.panel {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  /* Set flex here,
     and set flex-grow: 1 for the main element. */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bar {
  background-color: rgba(0,128,255,0.5);
  padding: 20px;
}

header {
  background-color: #9c9;
  padding: 10px;
}

main {
  min-height: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #c9c;
  /* Use not height here but flex in the .panel element,
     and set flex-grow:1 here. */
  /* height: 100%; */
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.item {
  background-color: #cc9;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas">
  <div class="bar" id="bar1">Bar 1</div>
  <div class="panel" id="panel1">
    <header>Panel 1</header>
    <main>
      <div class="item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    </main>    
  </div>
  <div class="panel" id="panel2">
    <header>Panel 2</header>
    <main>
      <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    </main>    
  </div>
  <div class="bar" id="bar2">Bar 2</div>
  <div class="panel" id="panel3">
    <header>Panel 3</header>
    <main>
    </main>      
  </div>
  <div class="panel" id="panel4">
    <header>Panel 4</header>
    <main>
      <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```